# Elastic Search in TYPO3 7.6 custom extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I want implement [ElasticSearch](https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3.ElasticSearch) in TYPO3 7.6 But i don't know how to implement it inside my custom extension. Please help me here..!!

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [mksearch](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mksearch) extension, but it does not work on 7.6. You can still take a look at the code to see if you can re-use some parts of it.

Another place I would go to borrow some code is the [Elastic Search integration package for FLOW](https://github.com/Flowpack/Flowpack.ElasticSearch)